# Variable name as argument in function - ggplot R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make a plot that shows what is sold relative to a variable that tells me more about the company. I want a different plot for every kind of product( for example all sorts of fruits: apples, bananas). Next I want to make it easy to make these plots for other company variables as well.

I have working code for one variable but not for the function. It does not accept the argument like it is supposed to.  I know it has something to do with non-standard evaluation, but I don't manage to fix the issue.

```
MASTERDATA%>%
  group_by(COMPANY)%>%
  summarize(AMOUNT_COMP = (sum(AMOUNT, na.rm=TRUE)),
            Type=Type,
            COMP_VAR1=COMP_VAR1)%>%
  filter(!is.na(Type)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(COMP_VAR1,AMOUNT_COMP ), na.rm = TRUE)+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~Type,nrow=4)
```

Following code for function

```
plot_var_aantal<-function(vari){
eval(substitute(vari), MASTERDATA)
MASTERDATA%>%
  group_by(COMPANY)%>%
  summarize(AMOUNT_COMP = (sum(AMOUNT, na.rm=TRUE)),
            Type=Type,
            vari=vari)%>%
  filter(!is.na(Type)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(vari,AMOUNT_COMP ), na.rm = TRUE)+
  geom_point()+
  facet_wrap(~Type,nrow=4)

}
```

If I For example put plot_var_aantal("people") I get just the word people on x-axis with all the points in a straght line above it.

DATA example

| Productnr | Type | Amount | COMPANY | COMP_VAR1 | COMP_VAR2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | 29 | Company1 | 2 | 45 |
| 1 | Pear | 271 | Company2 | 2 | 45 |
| 3 | Apple | 565 | Company2 | 5 | 78 |
| 2 | Banana | 354 | Company2 | 12 | 36 |
| 2 | Pear | 984 | Company3 | 12 | 36 |
| 1 | Banana | 247 | Company3 | 2 | 45 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Please share a small example of your data using `dput(head(MASTERDATA))`.

Comment: Not sure, what you are trying to do. Perhaps replacing `vari = vari` by `{{ vari }} := vari` solves your problem. `vari` inside the `aes()` should also be curly-curlied.

Comment: Why do you have `Type=Type` and `vari=vari` in `summarise` ? What are they supposed to do?

Comment: @RonakShah I use them there, cause I found that otherwise I don't have these variables anymore to work with in later lines. For example plot or filter.

Comment: If those variables are the same throughout maybe you need to include them in `group_by` or to keep same number of rows use `mutate` instead of `summarise`.

Comment: @MartinGal I put a self made table that shows my data. I did this because my original dataset is really big and I hope this example is more clear.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you for the help! I think in my case I'll use the 2. group by both company and type, but not vari. So I'll use mutate; Allthoug group by is still confusing to use for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `plot_var_aantal` with a string like `"people"` you need to evalute `vari` as a symbol on the righthand side with `!!sym(vari)` and on the lefthand side you need to put it into a `glue` specification `"{vari}"`. The following code should work:

```
plot_var_aantal<-function(vari){
  eval(substitute(vari), MASTERDATA)
  MASTERDATA%>%
    group_by(COMPANY)%>%
    summarize(AMOUNT_COMP = (sum(AMOUNT, na.rm=TRUE)),
              Type=Type,
              "{vari}" := !!sym(vari)) %>% # changed this line 
    filter(!is.na(Type)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(!! sym(vari),AMOUNT_COMP ), na.rm = TRUE) + # changed this line
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~Type,nrow=4)
  
}
```

However, without seeing your data it is hard to figure out what `COMP_VAR1 = COMP_VAR1` is doing in your `dplyr::summarise` call. You are not using an aggregating function (like `mean` or `paste(..., collapse = ",")`) so the whole `summarise` is probably not summarising but returning data in the original length. Similarly the line `"{vari}" := !!sym(vari)` doesn't seem to make sense (although the non-standard evaluation when `vari` is a string, is correct).

Answer (score 2):

When passing column names as string you can use `.data` pronoun.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

plot_var_aantal<-function(vari){
  MASTERDATA%>%
    group_by(COMPANY)%>%
    summarize(AMOUNT_COMP = (sum(AMOUNT, na.rm=TRUE)),
              Type=Type,
              !!vari := .data[[vari]])%>%
    filter(!is.na(Type)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(.data[[vari]],AMOUNT_COMP), na.rm = TRUE)+
    geom_point()+
    facet_wrap(~Type,nrow=4)
}

plot_var_aantal("people")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `aes_string(vari, 'AMOUNT_COMP')` to refer to the column names as string, or assign `COMP_VAR1 = vari` in the `summarize` statement and use your original plot code.